Нужна ли запятая перед "как": нужно поступать как я говорю
Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в предложении:
"Какая разница, кто из вас больше неправ, если надо поступать как я говорю"?

Какая разница, кто из вас больше не прав, если надо поступать, как я говорю.
Запятая перед придаточным.
